# Non-OEM Biometric Software?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor, biometrics

Most of us with **fingerprint readers** and such devices probably use the software provided by the vendor, to enable `biometric OS login` or single sign-on functionality. However, I've recently wondered if there is any third-party software that will do the same thing.

> This would be similar to how you don't *need* the manufacturer's software to use a scanner, printer, or webcam - you just use their drivers and your choice of software.
>
> > Is there anything like this for fingerprint readers or other biometric devices?

---

Additional info from merged question: Many fingerprint readers and other **biometric authentication devices** come with software for single-factor authentication to the OS.

> Is there any third-party software (F/OSS or otherwise) available for making OS authentication a two-factor process, such as by requiring both a fingerprint and a passcode?

---

Free or Open Source projects are preferred, but I'd be interested in learning about any existing solutions regardless. I personally am particularly interested in **Windows-compatible** software, but I'll leave the query open for any OS.

Comment: Interesting question, I was kind of wondering if something to this effect was available as well. I never found anything. Also like facial recognition as well would be cool. I've found propitiatory ones, but nothing free and open source.

Comment: AFAIK Windows 7 includes built-in biometric support.

Comment: @kinokijuf Yes, but without any third-party apps it's useless.

Answer (score 1):

HP Protect Tools Security Manager integrates well with Windows and it lets you configure requirements to require a fingerprint and password if you want. I haven't had a look at any other current ones.

Comment: Does this qualify as "Non-OEM"?  Will it work on systems without HP hardware?

Comment: @Iszi - erm - good point. Check out my inability to properly read the question. I'm pretty certain it's only HP biometric hardware that is supported.

Comment: To your credit, I believe this answer was originally in response to the pre-merge "two-factor authentication" question.  However, that one did (albeit perhaps more generally) specify "third-party".  In any case, it's nice to know this for my personal reference since I primarily have HP products at home.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to also look at a company called Softex, www.softexinc.com - I believe that they have a solution which will allow multi-factor authentication configuration as well.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Softex's OmniPass products do support multi-factor authentication.  It should be noted that the consumer-grade product costs around $50, and extra plugin purchases (approx. $5) may be required for certain authentication devices.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [pam module](http://freshmeat.net/projects/pam_bioapi/) which certainly supports [fingerprint scanning](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_enable_the_fingerprint_reader), and its trivial to configure pam to use n-factor authentication.

Of course, pam (only?) works on Linux, Solaris, BSD, most flavours of Unix but I beleive that there's at least one port to a MSWindows Gina floating about somewhere.

Comment: Note to the uninformed, MS' GINA is only applicable to pre-Vista, i.e. Windows XP and Server 2003.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an open source project on facial recognition:

http://code.google.com/p/pam-face-authentication/

It doesn't look like there's a big market for regular users needing two-factor authentication software on standalone machines.  Looking at some of the products out there look like an enterprise solution is more common.  At one time I eve developed my own two factor authentication system for a website using keystroke dynamics ([see the live demo](http://santiagodevelopment.com/biometrics)) but I'm not too sure about modifying an OS such as windows to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

linux already has this, it's just a couple PAM modules and some libs.

http://www.qrivy.net/~michael/blua/